# anyone else getting symbol lookup error mkl_serv_getenv with pandas series division?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

So this doesn't happen with most float series.  And I'm not sure what error in my 1.4 M entries causes the problem, but:

```
(Pdb) len(dum)
1400878
(Pdb) type(dum)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
(Pdb) dum.min()
2.0
(Pdb) dum.max()
823.0
(Pdb) 1.0 / dum
python: symbol lookup errorpython:      /home/gvelez/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-  packages/numexpr/../../../libmkl_vml_avx.so: undefined symbol: mkl_serv_getenv
```

: symbol lookup error: python/home/gvelez/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-  packages/numexpr/../../../libmkl_vml_avx.so: : symbol lookup errorundefined     symbol: mkl_serv_getenv: /home/gvelez/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numexpr/../../../libmkl_vml_avx.so: 
    undefined symbol: mkl_serv_getenv

I can work around it by getting the data out and doing the division in python, then putting it back.  that works fine.  But is there a correct pandas solution to this?

Comment: *Has anyone else had this problem?* is a polling question, not a programming question. If someone says *Yes, I've had this problem.* will that be wholly sufficient answer? If not, then your question needs restating. What specific *programming related question* do you have that we can help you with?

Answer (score 3):

oh - never mind, I probably need to run conda update -all

https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/2031

but right now I'm running my workaround, will test later