# Python pandas: Column unable to divide

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this

```
                        time      sym       ask0        ask1       ask2  \
date                                                                      
2017-08-21 07:00:00 07:00:00   b'7YR'  100.81250  100.828125  100.84375   
2017-08-21 07:00:15 07:00:15   b'7YR'  100.81250  100.828125  100.84375   
2017-08-21 07:00:30 07:00:30   b'7YR'  100.81250  100.828125  100.84375   
2017-08-21 07:00:45 07:00:45   b'7YR'  100.81250  100.828125  100.84375   
2017-08-21 07:01:00 07:01:00   b'7YR'  100.81250  100.828125  100.84375   
2017-08-21 07:01:15 07:01:15   b'7YR'  100.81250  100.828125  100.84375   
2017-08-21 07:01:30 07:01:30   b'7YR'  100.81250  100.828125  100.84375   
2017-08-21 07:01:45 07:01:45   b'7YR'  100.81250  100.828125  100.84375   
2017-08-21 07:02:00 07:02:00   b'7YR'  100.81250  100.828125  100.84375   
2017-08-21 07:02:15 07:02:15   b'7YR'  100.81250  100.828125  100.84375
```

The columns `ask0 ask1 ask2` are all `float64`

Addition(+) multiplication(*) and even integer division(//) work fine. For example

```
df['mid'] = (df['ask0'] + df['ask1'])*0.5
df['mid'] = (df['ask0'] + df['ask1'])//2
```

However, if I tried to divide float, I get this error

```
df['mid'] = (df['ask0'] + df['ask1'])/2
python: symbol lookup error: /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numexpr/../../../libmkl_vml_mc3.so: undefined symbol: mkl_serv_getenv
```

**UPDATE**:
I found out that if my series has less than 10,000 rows, then I can divide. But if it goes over 10,000 rows then it crashes. Can someone confirm?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10500, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
print(df.head())
df['A'] = df['A']/5
```

The solution I came up with was to use a batch divide method. But I just want to know if its true that Pandas can only divide df with size less than 10,000.

Comment: Try `df['mid'] = (df['ask0'] + df['ask1']).div(2)`

Comment: Why can't I use / ?  .div(2) did not work.

Comment: Not really sure.  / works in my environment.

Comment: Do you have https://docs.continuum.io/mkl-optimizations/ installed in your environment?

Comment: Look at this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43218191/anyone-else-getting-symbol-lookup-error-mkl-serv-getenv-with-pandas-series-divis)

Comment: Yes, I saw that post. However, I tried using divide on a smaller dataframe, and it works just fine... Could it be that it's due to the size of my dataframe that pandas is unable to divide??

Comment: @Telenoobies don't think that should be a problem

Comment: would `df['mid'] = df['ask0']/2 + df['ask1']/2` give the same error?

Comment: @AsheKetchum Same error.

Comment: @Telenoobies what if you tried to split up your big data frame, say the first 1000 columns, does is still give error?

Comment: @Telenoobies also maybe check the entries of those 2 columns with `value_counts()` or something, see if there are any weird values that might mess with algebraic operations.

Comment: I did a `value_count()`. Everything looks like a `float64`

Comment: Even doing something like this did not work `df_test = pd.to_numeric(df['ask0']);
df_test['ask0'] = df_test['ask0']/5`

Comment: I also experienced this issue and solved it with one of the suggestions [here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/2031) though I don't remember which one. It happened to me after I updated pandas.

Comment: As for the size of the DataFrame: pandas uses numexpr for larger frames so that's why you don't get the error for small ones.

Comment: @ayhan What is numexpr? Thank you for the clarification.